# Cant read and manipulate excel data

Tags: php, import-from-excel

I'm trying to read an `excel.xlsx` file. But I just can't, I'm reading about an API called `PHPExcel` but I can't make it work. This is what I tried:

```
<?php
    // get access to the class
    require_once 'Classes/PHPExcel.php';
    include 'Classes/IOFactory.php';

    $inputFileName = 'teste.xlsx';

    //  Read your Excel workbook
    try{
        $inputFileType = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($inputFileName);
        $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
        $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFileName);
    } 
    catch(Exception $e) {
        die('Error loading file "'.pathinfo($inputFileName,PATHINFO_BASENAME).'": '.$e->getMessage());
    }

    //  Get worksheet dimensions
    $sheet = $objPHPExcel->getSheet(0); 
    $highestRow = $sheet->getHighestRow(); 
    $highestColumn = $sheet->getHighestColumn();

    //  Loop through each row of the worksheet in turn
    for ($row = 1; $row <= $highestRow; $row++){ 
        //  Read a row of data into an array
        $rowData = $sheet->rangeToArray('A' . $row . ':' . $highestColumn . $row,NULL, TRUE, FALSE);  

       echo $rowData[$row];
    }

?>
```

at the end of the for loop, I tried to read or `echo` the data, but I got errors like: `Undefined offset`.

Comment: Doesn't `rangeToArray` return an array of cell data of each successive row? If so, and you want to read the cells from each row, then you'd probably want to use a different index to loop through each of those.